# Using result to change value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following JQuery script, but it appears not to be changing the value of the input. Ideally I would like to change the input to `data` but I am trying to simplify the issue as much as possible, hence using `test`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/individualcats.php',
        data: {venueid: 4},
        success: function(data) {
            $('#e12').val('test');
        },
    })
});
```

This is using select2, but I have tested the input statement on its own as so, and it works correctly:

```
$('#e12').val('test');
```

Comment: What do you mean by "value"? If you mean the inner contents of the div, try `$('#e12').html('test');` instead of `val`.

Comment: If it isn't succeeding then there is an error. Add an error handler to your AJAX request. Also watch your browser's console - it will reveal errors and other problems to you.

Comment: To point1, I meant the value of the input ie `<input value='test'>`. To point 2, i have used `console.log(data)` to check it succeeds and it works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using select2:

`$("#e12").select2("val", "test");`

http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/#documentation

Comment: I have tried this also and it is not setting the value

Comment: From the documentation I linked above: "Notice that in order to use this method you must define the initSelection function in the options so Select2 knows how to transform the id of the object you pass in val() to the full object it needs to render selection. If you are attaching to a select element this function is already provided for you."

Comment: Isnt this the case for standard selects, but in this case it is in Tag mode (bound to an `<input>`. Therefore there are no ids, just single strings

Comment: You're really leaving me stabbing in the dark here. What does your HTML look like? How are you instantiating select2? What does `data` look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#e12').val('test');
```

should work correctly for `value`. if you want to display it in input as text, you will need to use

```
$('#e12').text('test');
```